# WiX detect .Net 4.0.3

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have an application that requires .Net 4.0.3 ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600211)).

I've found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318785) which tells me where I would find the version of .Net which is installed but all I can find is the list of included properties that the WiX compiler recognises ([here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html)).

I've tried following the directions in [this article](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html), which tells me to use the following code, but this just installs .Net 4 without the update:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>

<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0.3. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
```

How would I go about making WiX check for the specific 4.0.3 update, either through a pre-defined WiX property or checking the registry value myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading, I ended up adding a bundle project to my solution that references my main `Product` in the standard WiX installer project (`MyProject.Installer`). I then used a `RegistrySearch` to find the version of the full .Net 4 installation.

```
<Bundle ....>
    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full" />
        <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx403Update" />
        <MsiPackage Id="MyMsi" SourceFile="$(var.MyProject.Installer.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
<Fragment>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Version"
                     Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
                     Value="Version"
                     Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion"
                     Win64="yes" />
    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
        <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
              DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
              DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </PackageGroup>

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx403Update">
        <ExePackage Id="Netfx403Update"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)NDP40-KB2600211-x86-x64.exe" 
              DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (Netfx4FullVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4.0.3&quot; OR Netfx4FullVersion &lt;&lt; &quot;4.5&quot;)" />
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

The condition expands out to `Netfx4FullVersion AND (Netfx4FullVersion << "4.0.3" OR Netfx4FullVersion << "4.5")` without XML escaping.

The following articles were helpful:

[Bundle skeleton code](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/authoring_bundle_skeleton.html)

[Bundle package manifest](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/authoring_bundle_package_manifest.html)

[Defining searches using WiX variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_define_searches.html)

[Chaining packages into a bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_author_chain.html)

[How to check for .Net versions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html)

Comment: Hi, I do not understand what are you accomplishing with this? You are querying for the version of .NET framework, which will not change when update is installed. If .NET framework 4.0 is installed, Version field will show 4.0.30319, no matter if update is installed or not. Am I missing something in your solution? Should you not use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended\KB2600211\?

Comment: If you download a recent version of the .Net framework, is update 4.0.3 not included in the package? I remember testing this on fresh virtual machines to make sure the installer worked correctly. If you've tried this and it doesn't work and you have another solution, feel free to post it.

Comment: No, it is not part of .net 4.0 (we need to wait for sp). I am also testing it on VM, and the proposed solution does not work properly. You could search for 4.0.3 registry key (which I have posted in previous post), however, I am still not sure that this is the correct way (searching for 4.0.3 key), since on my developer machine I do not have 4.0.3 installed, and async BCL is still working (I do not know if your app requires this update because of using async BCL).

Comment: My application requires 4.0.3 for LocalDb support. Have you got working code that you can post as an answer? I'll gladly change the accepted answer if it works =]

Answer (score 3):

Version value within the registry key `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"` will be always 4.0.30319 for .net 4.0 (even if updates have been installed).

Here is the code I have used in my bundle to search if the .net 4.0.3 version was already installed:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" 
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.3"
    Result="exists" 
    Variable="Netfx403" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"  
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.3" 
    Result="exists"
    Variable="Netfx403x64"
    Win64="yes" />
```

Then in your ExePackage DetectCondition:

```
DetectCondition="Netfx403 AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx403x64)"
```